# SQL Join request from two server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two databases on two different servers that I want to join two tables from.

I have no relation between them but just a column which contains information about the other database.

For example: `Database1.dbo.informationCity` contains a column `Specification` and have this information:

```
'14042020111925_GMS3439_09_04_2020-04_48.xml_6456.zip '
```

I want to extract from this column just this number 3439 because with this number I can rely the other database.

Example: `Database2.dbo.city` contains a column `cityID` with the value `3439`

Does anybody have an idea how to do that?

I tried this SQL request but it did not work:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    [Database1].[dbo].[Specification]
INNER JOIN 
    [Database2].[dbo].[city ] ON substring([Specification], CHARINDEX('GMS', [Specification ]) + 3,4) = [Database2].[dbo].[city].[cityID]
```

Comment: FYI, 3+ part naming for referencing columns is due to be removed from SQL Server. Use 2 Part naming, ideally aliasing your tables, to make the query succinct.

Comment: What about what you had, didn't work? "Did not work" doesn't tell us the *why*.

Comment: @Larnu because it is not correct, i want to extract the 4 digit number after the GMS from that :  14042020111925_GMS3439_09_04_2020-04_48.xml_6456.zip

Comment: it would be just 3439

Comment: If you just want to extract the number, there you don't need a `JOin`, Just use your `SUBSTRING` expression. Perhaps the reason it didn't work (which you still haven't explained) is because you reference the columns `[Specification]` and `[Specification ]` (notice the latter has white space at the end). Is this just a typographical error?

Comment: Also, does your table in `Database2` *really* have a trailing whitespace in it's name too? YOu type `[city ]` in the `FROM` but `[city]` in the `ON`. I am voting to close this as typographical, as it seems you're adding white space to object names where there shouldn't be (and without the reason *why* it "did not work" it seems like a safe bet, as the query *will* fail due to this typographical errors).

Comment: @Larnu  ok i understand you , as a first step i would like to extract this 4 digit after GMS word ? i am beginner with SQL , can you help with this Substring to get my result

Comment: '14042020111925_GMS3439_09_04_2020-04_48.xml_6456.zip '
==== >  3439

Comment: But the `SUBSTRING` ***works***. You *still* haven't said  why "it did not work", and (with respect) after asking 3 times and being ignored I'm not asking again.

Comment: @Larnu sorry sir, i did not mean that , i revised my code and i found an error , u r right , here is the structure my 2 database : Database1 contain Table named : informationCity and this one contain a column named : Specification ,,,,,,,,,,, Database2 contain Table named : city and this one contain a column named : cityID , i want to rely Specification with cityID

Comment: and to do that i must pick the 4digit after GMs word  from Specification Column and join it with CityID which has the same 4 digit